# Display Results on page, then Insert Multiple Records into MySQL table using ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I created the following page that displays which managers have accrued time for the current month.
- First, I need to display the records for reviewing,
- Then check the box, hit "Submit" & add them to the database.
- All from the same page or action page if required.

I've seen examples of using CFLOOP to insert multiple records, but not sure how to implement into my page since I'm displaying a "varying number" of records?

```
<!--- Create the Manager Monthly Accruals (Mgt) dataset --->
  <cfquery name="rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals" datasource="care">
   SELECT    username AS ltUser, accrued AS ltHours
     FROM      tblusers
   WHERE     clr_accrual = '1' AND hiredate  IS NOT NULL
  </cfquery>
```

I then display the results on my page like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">    
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" title="Check this box and click Submit button to add Accruals to database." /></td>
        <td>ltUser</td>
        <td>ltHours</td>
      </tr>
      <cfoutput query="rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals">
        <tr>
          <td>#rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals.ltUser#</td>
          <td>#rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals.ltHours#</td>
        </tr>
      </cfoutput>
</table>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" title="Check box & Submit to insert the Hours listed above for each User."/>
```

Here is what my page looks like: (just an HTML table that dynamically displays the records to view before inserting)

[image]

Question: How do I Insert the "x" number of query results for (ltUser & ltHours) into tblLeaveTime WHERE "checkbox" = 1 ?

Comment: I do not see any form fields. What exactly are you trying to insert? *RE:  not sure how to implement into my page since I'm displaying a "variable number" of records?* A good search phrase is [coldfusion dynamic form fields](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[coldfusion]%20dynamic%20form%20fields).

Comment: @Leigh , I need to INSERT (on a monthly basis) the output of my "rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals" query above, but since it can have "x" number of records, I'm not sure how to build the INSERT query? The fields to insert are: username, status, management_accrual.

Comment: Okay, but obviously you need to add some form fields first ;-) Did review the search results above? This is a pretty common task and there are a bunch of threads describing the most common approaches for handling this.

Comment: Yes, your post here was very insightful (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436110/iterate-through-a-dynamically-created-table-and-insert-data-into-sql-server-tabl/15436623#15436623) but how do I add form fields for a "yet undefined" number of records? That's why I just created a dynamic table view on my page that would show all the records in a list? thanks for the help.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean by "yet undefined". If the fields are generated from a query, then the number of records is known. Inside the query loop, use `queryName.currentRow` as the counter number. Then *outside* the loop, use `queryName.recordCount` to store the total number in a hidden field.

Comment: @Leigh, I simplified my question.

Comment: Does that table have a PK / unique ID for those records?

Comment: Yes, tblUsers is (ID, INT, 11, Auto_Increment), tblLeaveTime is (ltID, INT, 11, Auto_Increment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to make the checkbox *value* the unique record ID. I would also recommend giving the checkbox a more descriptive name.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="userIDList" value="#ID#" ...>
```

The selected id's will then be passed to the action page as a comma delimited list. You can then use that list to insert the selected records into another table with an INSERT / SELECT. (Obviously add validation to ensure something was selected first.)

```
   INSERT INTO OtherTable ( UserID, AccruedHours )
   SELECT ID, Accrued 
   FROM   tblUsers 
   WHERE  ID IN 
          (
            <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.userIDList#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true"> 
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Leigh and your excellent help! The checkbox tip was the fix (name="userIDList" value="#ID#")

Here is the final working Insert.cfm (some html stripped out)

```
    <!--- Create the Manager Monthly Accruals (Mgt) dataset --->
      <cfquery name="rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals" datasource="care">
    SELECT    tblusers.ID, username as ltUser, status, active, email, hiredate, tblUsers.picture AS eP
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, hiredate, NOW()) AS year_passed
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, hiredate, NOW()) MOD 12 AS month_passed
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, hiredate, NOW()) MOD 365 AS day_passed
    , CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, hiredate, NOW())," years, ",TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, hiredate, NOW()) MOD 12," months, ",TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, hiredate, NOW()) MOD 365," days") AS EmployLengthActive
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, hiredate, NOW()) AS monthly_accrual_time

    , CASE WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) < 1
     THEN '0'
     WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) <= 5
     THEN '14'
     WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) >= 6
     THEN '18'
     END AS ltHours


    FROM      v_reports_to_mgt_list LEFT OUTER JOIN tblusers ON tblusers.ID = v_reports_to_mgt_list.id
    WHERE     clr_accrual = '1' AND hiredate  IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY  hiredate
    </cfquery>

    <!-- Add a checkbox to Select / Deselect All -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    checked=false;
    function checkedAll (frm1) {
        var aa= document.getElementById('form1');
         if (checked == false)
              {
               checked = true
              }
            else
              {
              checked = false
              }
        for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++) 
        {
         aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
        }
          }
    </script>
    <!-- Script by hscripts.com -->
.....html....
<form action="leave_time_manager_accruals_insert.cfm" method="post" id="form1">    
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll(form1);'> Check All?</td>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>Hiredate</td>
        <td>Employee Length</td>
        <td>Management_Accrual</td>
      </tr>
      <cfoutput query="rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals">
        <tr class="#iif(currentrow MOD 2,DE('lightrow'),DE('darkrow'))#">
          <td><img src="../images/employees/#eP#" alt="" width="24" height="28" title=""/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="userIDList" value="#ID#" title="Check this box and click Submit button to add Leave Time Accruals to database." /></td>
          <td>#rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals.ltUser#</td>
          <td>#rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals.status#</td>
          <td>#rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals.active#</td>
          <td>#rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals.hiredate#</td>
          <td>#rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals.EmployLengthActive#</td>
          <td><div align="center">#rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals.ltHours#</div></td>
        </tr>
      </cfoutput>
   <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" title="Clicking this button will add all checked Managers Leave Time Accruals to database."/></td>
</table></form>
```

Here is the final working Action.cfm (some html stripped out)

```
<cfparam name="form.ltUser" default="">
<cfparam name="form.ltHours" default="">
<cfparam name="form.userIDList" default="1">

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Leave Time Added</title>
</head>

<body>

<cfquery name="rsInsertLeaveTimeManagerAccruals" datasource="care">
INSERT INTO tblLeaveTime ( ltUser, ltHours, ltCreated, ltType, ltCreatedBy)
   SELECT  v_reports_to_mgt_list.reports_to, 
   CASE WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) < 1
 THEN '0'
 WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) <= 5
 THEN '14'
 WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) >= 6
 THEN '18'
 END AS ltHours, NOW(), "Accrual", "cf_admin"
   FROM      v_reports_to_mgt_list LEFT OUTER JOIN tblusers ON tblusers.ID = v_reports_to_mgt_list.id
   WHERE  v_reports_to_mgt_list.ID IN 
          (
            <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.userIDList#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true"> 
          )
</cfquery>
<h1>Management Leave Time successfully added to  database! </h1>
Click <a href="leave_time_mgt_l01.cfm">here</a> to return to Admin page
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the working solution. Couple suggestions A) Consider changing the list default to something that is *not* likely to be a valid ID, like `0` B) Redirect users to a different page after the INSERT to minimize the likelihood the records will be inserted twice if the user accidentally refreshes the page (or modify the query to prevent duplicates).